# multiple validations based on action with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

how can have different validations depending on the action?

```
validates :total_pressed,
          :numericality => { :on => :create, :greater_than => 0 },
          :numericality => { :on => :update, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 100 }
```

the first numericality statement is ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you validate first numericality statement is ignored because it`s hash and one thing rewrite another

You can do this:

```
validates :total_pressed, :numericality => { :on => :create, :greater_than => 0 }
validates :total_pressed, :numericality => { :on => :update, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 100 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use validate_on_create and validate_on_update

```
def validate_on_create # is only run the first time a new object is saved
  errors.add(:total_pressed, 'invalid number') if total_pressed < 0
end

def validate_on_update
  errors.add(:total_pressed, 'invalid number') if total_pressed < 100
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the validation operates on both create and update (via save), so if you pass the on flag then you'll limit it to either of the two methods. If you want to have different validation based on the action, then you're best off using a custom validation.

i.e

```
validate :total_pressed_on_create, :total_pressed_on_update

def total_pressed_on_create
  errors.add(:total_pressed, 'invalid number') if self < 0 and self.new_record?
end

def total_pressed_on_update
  errors.add(:total_pressed, 'invalid number') if self < 100 and !self.new_record?
end
```

Something along those lines. Check [Rails Guide: Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods) for more details.